# java.sql.SQLException:[MicroSoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Acces]Définition de l'attribut impossible a ce stage

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, odbc

I want to check if there is no data on table before inserting ,but a message  appear : java.sql.SQLException:[MicroSoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Acces]Définition de l'attribut impossible  a ce stage

MY CODE:

```
    try {
        String sqll = "Select * from CG1";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sqll);
         rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        nam = rs.getString(1);

    }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
               if (nam == null || Integer.parseInt(nam.toString())==0) {
    try {

        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into CG1(Exe,Mois,Journal)values(?,?,?)");

        for (int i = 0; i < dtm.getRowCount(); i++) {
            String exe = dtm.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
            String mois = dtm.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
            String journal = dtm.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();

            pst.setString(1, exe);
            pst.setString(2, mois);
            pst.setString(3, journal);

            pst.addBatch();
        }
        pst.executeBatch();
        con.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems that a space is missing here `(Exe,Mois,Journal)`>< `values(?,?,?)`

Comment: that's not the  problem ,the insert query work well,but when I put it on if() condition ,the message (java.sql................)appear, it's look like there is a mistake on operation condition !!?

Answer (score 0):

Finally problem resolved, should remove commit and auto commit from IF() condition and the program perfectly work